# Kubernetes Traefik, keep getting service unavailable

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

Anybody know why I keep getting service unavailable for the below YAML code. The ingress points to the service which points to the container and it should be working. For this example I am just using an NGINX container to test.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.example.services
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: web

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.15.4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
```

Comment: to debug the issue, run a pod with curl in the same environment and try to access the service directly without ingress (http://frontend/). if it works, try to use an ingress rule with no host, otherwise check nginx pod logs for clues.

Comment: How do you try to access the service?

Comment: Ok guys this is resolved, I had to remove the selector: k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb because it wasn't part of the endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service had a selector which the app didn't. Once the label `k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb` was removed everything worked fine.

Thanks to Daniel Tomcej on the Traefik Slack channel for helping me out here.

Answer (score 1):

If you using [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/) as ingress controller then, documentation might be misleading. Below you can see an example of ingress controller form traefik website. The same configuration returned **503 error** for my application. It turned out that, I had to change `servicePort: http` to `servicePort: 80` and this change fixed the problem!

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cheese
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: stilton.minikube
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: stilton
          servicePort: http
      ...
```